# Scattering Instances on Upward Facing Normals

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I am a newbie to Geometry Nodes am am trying to scatter some instances on a mesh, **but only on the upward facing normals.** Is there any way for geometry nodes to do this?

If not, is there any way to only scatter instances on upward-facing *faces?* That could work for me to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here the node `Compare` helps you.

[image]

Set this to *Vector*, *Dot Product* and *Greater Than or Equal*, and use as second vector $(0,0,1)$ (pointing up).

This selects the upward pointing faces, which you can use directly with `Distribute Points on Faces`.

Comment: Once again, you are the best. Thanks so much! 

Comment: @BlenderMaster15 Thank you! You're welcome!