# Upwards pointing Normals in Geometry Nodes in world coordinates (when object ist rotated)

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry, vector

I would like to get the same thing done in Geometry Nodes as was done here in Shading.
[image]

I want to create points only on the faces pointing upwards. This should also be the case when the object is rotated. But unfortunately the points simply rotate with the sphere. What can I do about this?

[image]

There is already a similar question here:

[Scattering Instances on Upward Facing Normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/286464/scattering-instances-on-upward-facing-normals)

However, only the local normals are taken into account here. When the object is rotated, the normals rotate with it, which I don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rotate the normal vector accordingly to the object rotation.

The rotation can be obtained by the "object info" node, using itself ("self object" node) as input.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, lemon! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

of course Lemon's answer is right, but here is just another way doing it:

[image]

and here only for lemon:

[image]

Comment: Bigger image for the node tree please (take care of old eyes that are reading you!! ;) ... but +1 of course

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris! But the answer from lemon was what I was looking for. In your answer the normals are not considered, but the position on the Z axis.